# python subprocess won't interleave stderr and stdout as what terminal does

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

A test program

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys

count = 0
sys.stderr.write('stderr, order %d\n' % count)
count += 1
sys.stdout.write('stdout, order %d\n' % count)
count += 1
sys.stderr.write('stderr, order %d\n' % count)
count += 1
sys.stdout.write('stdout, order %d\n' % count)
```

when invoked through the terminal, the expected output is,

```
stderr, order 0
stdout, order 1
stderr, order 2
stdout, order 3
```

In the interactive shell, when I redirect `stdout` to a PIPE, the output order is different from the output above, where Popen would group `stderr` and write them all and then do the same thing to `stdout`, instead of interleaving stdout and stderr.

```
In [29]: a = sp.run(['./test.py'], stderr=sp.STDOUT)
stderr, order 0
stdout, order 1
stderr, order 2
stdout, order 3

In [30]: a
Out[30]: CompletedProcess(args=['./test.py'], returncode=0)

In [33]: b = sp.Popen(['./test.py'], stderr=sp.STDOUT, stdout=sp.PIPE, encoding='utf-8')

In [34]: print(b.communicate()[0])
stderr, order 0
stderr, order 2
stdout, order 1
stdout, order 3
```

Answer (score 3):

In the C libraries (and thus c-based python), streams are handled differently depending on whether they are attached to interactive terminals (or something pretending to be) or not. For a `tty`, `stdout` is line buffered, otherwise its block buffered and only flushed to the file descriptor when some block boundary is hit. When you redirected to a PIPE, the stream is no longer a tty and block buffering is in effect.

The solution is to reopen `stdout` specifying that you want line buffering (1) regardless. At the C level, `stderr` is always line buffered but when I tested just reopening `stdout` the program acted as though `stderr` is block  buffered. I was quite surprised. Maybe this is the intermediate `io.TextIO` layer or some other odd thing, but I found I needed to fix both pipes.

Even though `stdout` and `stderr` go to the same pipe, they are separate file descriptors with separate buffers as far as the executed program is concerned. That's why interleaving doesn't happen naturally in the output buffer even in block mode.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import os

# reopen stdout line buffered
sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', 1)

# this surprises me, seems like we have to reopen stderr
# line buffered, but i thought it was line buffered anywy.
# perhaps its the intermediate python TextIO layer?
sys.stderr = os.fdopen(sys.stderr.fileno(), 'w', 1)

count = 0
sys.stderr.write('stderr, order %d\n' % count)
count += 1
sys.stdout.write('stdout, order %d\n' % count)
count += 1
sys.stderr.write('stderr, order %d\n' % count)
count += 1
sys.stdout.write('stdout, order %d\n' % count)
```