# Python Unittests output - Is it possible to print out the print statements within unittests under each pass/fail row?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have many print statements within my unittest test methods and I would like to be able to see them printed out underneath each "ok" row in the console output.  Does anyone have a way to do this?  Thank you.

```
test_01...ok
This is a print statement for test 1
test_02...ok
This is a print statement for test 2
test_03...ok
This is a print statement for test 3
```

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is verbosity, `runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2)`.

The longer answer, if you want to store the output streams is more complicated.
`std.io` and `std.err` are managed by the OS and [they are flushed differently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60253731/2541138) when connected to the terminal than when redirected to a file.

Some examples,
Unit under test (filename `testablepython.py`)

```
def run():
    print(f"{__name__} unit print")
    return(True)
```

test code body (filename `test/test_tests.py`)

```
import unittest
import logging
import testablepython as unit
import os
import sys
# import pandas as pd

class Test_ClassOne(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_A(self):
        self.assertTrue(unit.run())
        logging.info('log: passed test_one'

    def test_B(self):
        self.assertFalse(not unit.run())
        logging.info('log: passed test_falseisnottrue')

class Test_ClassTwo(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_three(self):
        logging.info(f"log: in test_three, does not call unit")
        self.assertTrue(True)
```

the main block that works to console *but not on redirect*:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2)
    unittest.main(testRunner=runner)
```

console output:

```
$python -m test.test_tests
test_A (__main__.Test_ClassOne) ... testablepython unit print
INFO:root:log: passed test_one
ok
test_B (__main__.Test_ClassOne) ... testablepython unit print
INFO:root:log: passed test_falseisnottrue
ok
test_three (__main__.Test_ClassTwo) ... INFO:root:log: output three ['fred', 'alaska', 'baker']
ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.003s

OK
$
```

Note the lack of a newline between the test fixture and the `print()` code from the unit under test, no flush. On redirect the streams are un-mixed, `std.err` first then `std.io`.

```
$ python -m test.test_tests &> temp.txt
$ cat temp.txt
test_A (__main__.Test_ClassOne) ... INFO:root:log: passed test_one
ok
test_B (__main__.Test_ClassOne) ... INFO:root:log: passed test_falseisnottrue
ok
test_three (__main__.Test_ClassTwo) ... INFO:root:log: output three ['fred', 'alaska', 'baker']
ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.001s

OK
testablepython unit print
testablepython unit print
```

The solution seems to be to reconfigure the outputs to force them to flush during operation.
*solution:*

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

    sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', 1)
    sys.stderr = os.fdopen(sys.stderr.fileno(), 'w', 1)

    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner( verbosity=2)
    unittest.main(testRunner=runner)
```

Note the lack of a newline between the test fixture and the `print()` code from the unit under tesNow we get the desired redirected output:

```
$ python -m test.test_tests &> temp.txt
$ cat temp.txt
test_A (__main__.Test_ClassOne) ... testablepython unit print
INFO:root:log: passed test_one
ok
test_B (__main__.Test_ClassOne) ... testablepython unit print
INFO:root:log: passed test_falseisnottrue
ok
test_three (__main__.Test_ClassTwo) ... INFO:root:log: output three ['fred', 'alaska', 'baker']
ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.002s
```

Or we can see both by calling unittest with a [tee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/363239/2541138): `python -m test.test_tests  2>&1 | tee tmp.txt`